# Whisker not showing up in Bokeh plot

Tags: python, bokeh, boxplot

I had a homework problem recently where we were given a data set and asked to calculate some parameters for a model distribution, with confidence intervals. I wanted to make a quick plot with error bars to display the data, but I can't get the Whisker to show up at all. I'm using Bokeh 2.2.1 so I don't think it's a problem with the version, and the example whisker code from the Bokeh documentation works as well.

Here is the code I wrote for the plot:

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Whisker
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap

groups= ['Het', 'Wt', 'Mut']
vals = [mle_het[0], mle_wt[0], mle_mut[0]]
upper = [conf_int_het[1][0], conf_int_wt[1][0], conf_int_mut[1][0]]
lower = [conf_int_het[0][0], conf_int_wt[0][0], conf_int_mut[0][0]]

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(groups=groups, vals=vals, upper=upper, lower=lower))

p = figure(x_range=groups, plot_height=350, title="Mu MLEs with Error Bars @ 95% Confidence Interval", y_range=(0,40))

p.add_layout(
    Whisker(source=source, base="groups", upper="upper", lower="lower")
)

p.circle(x='groups', y = 'vals', size=15, source=source, legend_group="groups",
       line_color='white', fill_color=factor_cmap('groups', palette=["#962980","#295f96","#29966c"],
                                                  factors=groups))

p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.legend.orientation = "horizontal"
p.legend.location = "top_center"

show(p)
```

The vals, upper, and lower lists are just three floats each that I'm pulling from the data earlier in the code.

There's a link to the plot I'm getting, everything shows up fine except the error bars. I don't get any error messages either. If anyone has any idea how to fix it I'd be grateful!

[plot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5CtD.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug that'll be fixed in 2.3:
https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/10575